# Grails global error handler

Tags: grails

I've defined the following global error handlers in `UrlMappings.groovy`

```
    "404"(controller: "error", action: "notFound")
    "500"(controller: "error", action: "serverError")
```

The handlers are implemented like this:

```
class ErrorController {

    def notFound() {
        flash.msg = "Not Found"
        redirect uri: '/'
    }

    def serverError() {
        flash.msg = "Oops"
        redirect uri: '/'
    }
}
```

When a 404 error occurs everything works fine, but when a 500 error occurs the flash scope is empty when I redirect to `/`. Is there some reason why the flash scope should be cleared after a 500 (caused by an uncaught exception on the server)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have only one mapping for `500` error code?

Make sure you only have one mapping for 500 in `UrlMappings.groovy` (remove or comment out the default mapping provided by Grails on create-app)

```
static mappings = {
    "404"(controller: "error", action: "notFound")
    "500"(controller: "error", action: "serverError")

    "/"(view:"/index") //or whichever view you have for root context.
    //"500"(view:'/error') [Culprit]
}
```

It should work as expected with the above url mapping.

Well actually the placing matters, if you place your custom mapping for 500 after the default mapping provided by grails, then you would see your result as expected. The last mapping overrides the older one.

Comment: Yes, I only have one mapping, you can see the code here: https://github.com/domurtag/airport/blob/master/grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy

Comment: @Don I ran the project and deliberately threw 500 from an action. I was able to see the expected flash message. I upgraded the project to use Grails 2.2.3, right now I am downgrading to 2.1.5 again and testing the same. Will let you know the result.

Comment: @Don Update:- I was able to see "An error occurred while processing your request" message when tested with Grails 2.1.5 as well. Is that what you were unable to see in the home page?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I was unable to see, I wonder why you're seeing it and I'm not? What browser did you use? I doubt it's a browser issue though, because the 404 message displays and it's the same CSS/HTML/JS in both cases

Comment: @Don Were you able to get through it?

Comment: I haven't changed anything since I posted the question, so I guess the problem still exists

Comment: @Don Let me know if I can be of any help. :)